# Is there a way to TagSet a HoldAllComplete function?

Tags: function-construction, evaluation, associations, hold, attributes

Let's say I want to overload the built-in function `Lookup`, to handle my data wrapped in `myObject`. One would use `TagSet` or `TagsetDelayed` (`f /: lhs = rhs` or `f /: lhs := rhs`) like this:

```
ClearAll[myObject];
myObject /: Lookup[o_myObject, args___] := Lookup[First[o], args];
```

This won't work because the `HoldAllComplete` attribute of `Lookup` prevents checking the head of the argument (everything is done internal to `Lookup`, which I don't want to meddle with).

```
obj = myObject[<|a -> 1, b -> 2|>]
Lookup[Evaluate[obj], b]
```

> ```
> Lookup::invrl: The argument myObject[<|a->1,b->2|>] is not a
>                valid Association or a list of rules. >>
> ```

Is there any way to overload such a function to handle arbitrary input wrappers?

Comment: Probably not (that is, unless you want to add `DownValues` to `Lookup`, and I wouldn't do that). `HoldAllComplete` is hard to bargain with. But if you define your own data type, you could define your own heads for lookup. So, what are the cases where this is a real problem then?

Comment: One other thing you could try would be lexical substitutions / code generation. Something like `withLookup = Function[code, Unevaluated[code] /. HoldPattern[Lookup[o_myObject, args___]]:>Lookup[First@obj, args], HoldAll]`. But this is of course limited and can't be made fully dynamic without introducing a fully typed code (type system).

Comment: Thanks @Leonid for the always quick input! My use-case is exactly what I wrote: I had to introduce a new, completely inert data wrapper that holds a medium-sized `Association`. The wrapper is needed for all the other builtins so that I can overload them without interfering with the system; and I simply wanted to enjoy all the nice functionality of associations too with `Lookup`. But I can live with not being able to use `Lookup`, this is really not a big issue. I only wanted to know whether I've overlooked something obvious or not.

Comment: This post perhaps should be closed, as no oner will bother to make a full answer out of a simple "No"...

Comment: You could self-answer based on what is currently known. The votes indicate that people are interested. If we overlooked something, perhaps someone will enlighten us.

Comment: If you place the `args` as a second input for `myObject` then may be one can trick `Lookup` and call the evaluator using `PatternTest`. Something like this :`ClearAll[myObject, eval];
myObject /: (_[t : myObject[obj_, arg_]] /; (eval = Lookup @@ t)) := 
  Nothing;` Now : `obj = myObject[<|a -> 1, b -> 2|>, b] ;
Lookup[obj, _]; // Quiet;` and `eval` gives you `2`.

Comment: Thanks for the Accept.  Do my examples actually help solve a problem for you, or are you just resigned to what you really want not working?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks for the extra work. To be honest, I gave up on the issue shortly after posting, realizing that whatever I do, it won't be robust. So I left this project of mine for a year, and now that you provided some workaround, I thought that that's the best one can achieve. I'm not satisfied with your solution (extra `[]` is not nice), but I have to accept the limits. That is my main issue with _Mathematica_ recently: it is no use introducing new, compact objects (a la `FittedModel` for example) as one cannot really integrate it with System functions properly.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard My original context was as simple as my example: to have an object that stores lots of values in an association but is formatted as a compact thing (`myObject`), not to clutter the screen. But then I wanted to have all the `Association`-related facilties to work with it (like `Normal`, `Join`, `Lookup`, `Dataset`, etc.). And then I realized at `Lookup` that I couldn't do it. And I didn't want to introduce my own functions to go with `myObject`, as Leonid has suggested.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This "unanswered" question has been sitting for too long.

The documentation for [`HoldAllComplete`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldAllComplete.html) says (emphasis mine):

> `HoldAllComplete` not only prevents arguments from being evaluated, but also prevents `Sequence` objects from being flattened, `Unevaluated` wrappers from being stripped, *and upvalues associated with arguments from being used.*

So this attribute exists *expressly* to prevent upvalues such as the one you make from being active.

However since `Lookup` happily evaluates whatever first argument it is given you are free to use other evaluation rules on `myObject`, for example:

```
myObject[asc_Association][] := asc

obj = myObject[<|a -> 1, b -> 2|>];

Lookup[obj[], b]
```

> ```
> 2
> ```

This may be a tautology but your example doesn't make clear what you're really trying to do.

Perhaps you wish to escape from `Lookup` entirely.  This is one approach:

```
ClearAll[myObject]

myObject[asc_Association][] := 
  Return[#, Lookup] & /@ 
    Cases[Stack[_Lookup],
      HoldForm[Lookup[_, args___]] :>
        myLookupSurrogate[asc, args]
    ]

obj = myObject[<|a -> 1, b -> 2|>];

Lookup[obj[], b]
```

> ```
> myLookupSurrogate[<|a -> 1, b -> 2|>, b]
> ```

This still requires adding `[]` to a use of `obj` but it at least seems close to the spirit of what you're apparently seeking.