# How to prevent arguments UpValues from being used in selective functions

Tags: evaluation, associations, upvalues

Ok, I know the simple answer is to set some form of Hold attribute to the function but bear with me for a bit while I explain my motivation and why that is not quite what I want.

---

I have a collection of data that is naturally grouped together and some functions that operate on that data. To me, the obvious way to represent this is a struct-like data-type and an [Association](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association.html) seemed perfect for the job. There are a couple of questions and answers describing this approach on this site.

Great, now I have an association as follows: (Just an example)

```
<|
  "Atom Names" -> {"N","C","O","C","H","H"},
  "Atom Nr"    -> {56,23,117,81,211,5},
  "Resname"    -> {ALA,ALA,TYR,LEU,GLY,GLY},
  "Bias Value" -> {1,5,1,5,1,1}
  "getRandomAtom" :> RandomChoice[{56,23,117,81,211,5}],
  "atomExists" :> (MemberQ[{"N","C","O","C","H","H"},#]&)
|>
```

I have some other functions that operate on this collection of data.

```
f1[a_Association, args__] := a["getRandomAtom"] + Total[a["Atom Nr"]]
f2[a_Association, atom_String] := If[a[atomExists][atom], a["Bias Value"] + 1]
(*etc*)
```

Ideally these function would not just accept *any* `Association` but only the 'correct' type of `Association`. I can ensure this in a couple of ways. Eg. create a helper function and use `Condition` or `PatternTest` to check if the `Association` has all the correct keys or much more simply, I can just wrap the entire `Association` with a inert head.

```
Protect[atomData]
atomData[<|
  "Atom Names" -> {"N","C","O","C","H","H"},
  "Atom Nr"    -> {56,23,117,81,211,5},
  "Resname"    -> {ALA,ALA,TYR,LEU,GLY,GLY},
  "Bias Value" -> {1,5,1,5,1,1}
  "getRandomAtom" :> RandomChoice[{56,23,117,81,211,5}],
  "atomExists" :> (MemberQ[{"N","C","O","C","H","H"},#]&)
|>]
```

And in my functions, I can just check the heads.

```
f3[a_atomData,args__] := "Do Stuff"
```

But I'd like to retain the functionality of `Association` transparently. We can somewhat achieve this through the use of upvalues.

```
atomData[a_Association][key_] := a[key];
atomData /: h_[atomData[a_Association],args___] := h[a,args] 
(*And some additional stuff*)
atomData /: ToString[atomData[a_Association]] := a["Atom Names"]
atomData[a_Association][] := a
```

As [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/109657/) question notes, this will not work for all functions (eg. Lookup) as they have the `HoldAllComplete` attribute. (Coincidentally, my motivation is almost exactly the same as the OP of that question)

---

Here comes the problem. Since I defined these upvalues, my functions which check for the `Head` `atomData` won't work anymore.

```
f3[myatomdata,3,4] (* myatomdata has head atomData *)
```

The upvalues associated with atomData will be applied first and this will result in `f3[<|...(*underlying association*)...|>,3,4]`, which will not be evaluated as the first argument nolonger has the `Head` `atomData`.

```
SetAttributes[f3,HoldFirst]
```

won't help either, as in the function call `f3[myatomdata,3,4]`, the evaluator will leave `myatomdata` alone, which means that it will have `Head` `Symbol`, and once again f3 will not be evaluated.

---

It seems that I have defeated my entire purpose by setting these upvalues. Is there a better way to do what I want?

I can think of 2 ways, both of which seem quite ugly.

1. Modify the upvalue definition to exclude certain functions. Something like

   ```
    atomData /: 
    (h : Except[f1|f2|f3])[atomData[a_Association], args___] := h[a, args]
   ```

This seems particularly inelegant, as I'd have to modify this every time I add another function that will use `atomData`.

2. Do the head checking yourself.

   ```
    SetAttributes[f3,HoldFirst]
    atomData /: (h : Except[Head])[atomData[a_Association], args___] := h[a, args]
    f3[a_ /; Head[a]===atomData] := "Do Stuff"
   ```

The ideal solution would be a way to prevent *just* the upvalue from evaluating and leaving all others (OwnValues,DownValues etc.) alone.

---

PS. I'm also open to the idea that this whole approach is rubbish if someone can suggest a better way. I come from a background of C++, Java, and Python; Thinking of everything in terms of objects has been ingrained in me. Apologies for the long-winded explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might consider putting the "type" label inside an Association itself.  This will complicate key addressing but simplify other handling.

```
asc = <|"atomData" ->
    <|"Atom Names" -> {"N", "C", "O", "C", "H", "H"}, 
     "Atom Nr" -> {56, 23, 117, 81, 211, 5}, 
     "Resname" -> {ALA, ALA, TYR, LEU, GLY, GLY}, 
     "Bias Value" -> {1, 5, 1, 5, 1, 1}, 
     "getRandomAtom" :> RandomChoice[{56, 23, 117, 81, 211, 5}], 
     "atomExists" :> (MemberQ[{"N", "C", "O", "C", "H", "H"}, #] &)|>|>;

aDtest[a_Association /; Keys[a] === {"atomData"}] := True;

f1[a_?aDtest, args__] := a[[1]]["getRandomAtom"] + Total[a[[1]]["Atom Nr"]]

f1[asc, 2]
```

> ```
> 549
> ```

Using `a[[1]]` each time is only one way to approach this; others include:

```
f1[aa_?aDtest, args__] := 
  With[{a = aa[[1]]}, a["getRandomAtom"] + Total[a["Atom Nr"]]]
```

Or:

```
f1[a_?aDtest, args__] := f1core[a[[1]], args]

f1core[a_, args__] := a["getRandomAtom"] + Total[a["Atom Nr"]]
```

---

### For *Mathematica* 10.4 or later

The method above can be improved for recent versions of *Mathematica* as follows:

```
ClearAll[f1]

p1 = <|"atomData" -> a_|>;

f1[p1, args__] := a["getRandomAtom"] + Total[a["Atom Nr"]]

f1[asc, 2]
```

> ```
> 549
> ```

Reference:

- [MatchQ-ing Associations (MMA 10)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/55526/121)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. While this does simply many things with regards to handling (I don't have to mess with upvalues anymore), I don't think it is particularly better than my 2nd approach. The more complicated key addressing will produce more clutter or clutter scoping blocks everywhere than just creating the upvalue definitions once off. Plus when I have many of these `atomData` 'types' doing `With[{a1 = aa1[[1]], a2 = aa2[[1]] ...]` gets cumbersome. Any thoughts on the PS. part of my question? - if I should continue with the OO paradigm

Comment: @void If you are using *Mathematica* 10.4 or later please see my update and tell me if it is more to your liking.

Comment: That's neat, it seems like the most elegant solution right now. I'm using _Mathematica_ 11.3 so I can take advantage of it.

Answer (score 3):

You should definitely go the route of using an inert wrapper for the association, `atomData[Association[...]]`.

You can make a general subvalue like what you have,

```
atomData[a_Association][key_] := a[key];
```

and you can make more specific definitions like

```
atomData[a_Association]["getRandomAtom"] := 
       RandomChoice[a["Atom Names"]
```

and

```
atomData[a_Association]["atomExists", s_] := MemberQ[a["Atom Names"], s]
```

so that you don't need to waste space in your `atomData` for computed properties.  This definition however,

```
atomData /: h_[atomData[a_Association],args___] := h[a,args]
```

is, as you say, <s>pure rubbish</s> suboptimal. This upvalue is so general that it renders your object useless for any other purpose. Just try `{atomData[<|a->b|>],2}`.

I use `UpValues` so seldom, that I tend to see it as code smell, an indication you should rethink things (except [`Nothing`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nothing.html), I use `Nothing` in a lot of cases). In the above, the definition should be on `h` and not on `atomData`.

In your workarounds, you try to implement a list of special heads that shouldn't trigger an upvalue on `atomData`. Instead, it should be in the definition of the other functions to access the data in `atomData`:

```
f1[a:atomData[assoc_Association], args_] := f[ assoc, args]
f1[a_Association, args_] := ....
```

Write a definition like the above for every function you want to just work with the raw data directly. But the general behavior is for `atomData` head to **not disappear** whenever it's in some other expression.

A couple of other points:

You should use a more specific pattern than `_Association`.  Even `_?AssociationQ` is better, since it rules out things like `Association[1]`.  But in your case you could define a pattern:

```
$atomDataPattern = KeyValuePattern[ 
     {"Atom Names" -> {__String}, "Atom Nr" -> {__Integer} }
]
```

and so then you can use this in function definitions:

```
f[atomData[ad:$atomDataPattern], args] := f[ad,args]
```

You can then make a nice formatting for `atomData` using the functions described in [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/79891/9490).

If you want to program in Mathematica but keep to OOP methods you are used to, you might benefit from the package described [in this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/165486/9490).

Comment: Utilizing a full OOP package seems a bit overkill right now, but I'll keep them in mind for future. I'm not sure why I didn't make the computed properties as subvalues. Definitely a waste of memory. With regards to upvalues, the inital goal __was__  to make them as general as possible. I wanted it to behave seamlessly as an `Association` most of the time. The logic being that the number of 'special' functions will be smaller than the number of functions that `Associations` can work with. But as you've pointed out the other way is probably better. Thank you for the valuable suggestions.